# Python: libxml2 xpath returns empty list

Tags: python, list, xpath, libxml2

I want to parse XML content with Python's libxml2 using xpath, i followed [this example](http://simonwillison.net/2003/Oct/21/xpathRocks/) and [that tutorial](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html). The XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#" version="0.3">
<title>Gmail - Inbox for myemailaddress@gmail.com</title>
<tagline>New messages in your Gmail Inbox</tagline>
<fullcount>1</fullcount>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://mail.google.com/mail" type="text/html"/>
<modified>2011-05-04T18:56:19Z</modified>
</feed>
```

This XML is stored in a file called "atom", and i try the following:

```
>>> import libxml2
>>> myfile = open('/pathtomyfile/atom', 'r').read()
>>> xmldata = libxml2.parseDoc('myfile')
>>> data.xpathEval('/fullcount')
[]
>>>
```

Now as you can see it returns an empty list. No matter what i may provide xpath with, it will return an empty list. However, if i use the `*` wildcard, i get a list of all nodes:

```
>>>> data.xpathEval('//*')
[<xmlNode (feed) object at 0xb73862cc>, <xmlNode (title) object at 0xb738650c>, <xmlNode (tagline) object at 0xb73865ec>, <xmlNode (fullcount) object at 0xb738660c>, <xmlNode (link) object at 0xb738662c>, <xmlNode (modified) object at 0xb738664c>]
```

Now i don't understand, judging from the working examples above, why xpath doesn't find the "fullcount" node or any other: i'm using the same syntax after all...

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: And why should i? :) i am looking at the lxml doc now. Thanks.

Comment: it's a binding for libxml2. I wasn't even aware that there was an alternate binding, but lxml is very intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath is failing because you need to specify the **purl namespace** on the node:

```
import libxml2
tree = libxml2.parseDoc(data)
xp = tree.xpathNewContext()
xp.xpathRegisterNs("purl", "http://purl.org/atom/ns#")
print xp.xpathEval('//purl:fullcount')
```

Result:

```
[<xmlNode (fullcount) object at 0x7fbbeba9ef80>]
```

(Also: check out lxml, it has a nicer, higher-level interface).

Comment: Working answer thanks :) Now, what is a _purl namespace_? Could you explain please?

Comment: @Benjamin It is the default namespace for the document, defined on the feed tag: `<feed xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#" version="0.3">`. That is a shortcut to assign all nodes in the document to that namespace. So whenever you ask libxml2 about a node in this document and fail to include the namespace, it has no idea what you mean. :-)

Comment: thanks, i'm new to the concept of namespace. What does the namespace provide exactly, definitions?

Comment: @Benjamin namespaces are part of the XML standard, and lets elements and attributes from different worlds exist together in a single document without conflicting. For example, the node `image` might mean two different things, depending on the namespace, e.g. `foo:image`, `bar:image`. Namespaces usually correspond to some DTD or schema defining a type of document, such as the Atom feed format, which would define which elements/attributes you should expect to see in a document using that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly:**

`/fullcount` is an absolute path, so it's looking for the `<fullcount>` element in the root of the document, when the element is in fact within the `<feed>` element.

**Secondly:**

You need to specify the namespace. This is how you would do it with [**lxml**](http://lxml.de):

```
import lxml.etree as etree

tree = etree.parse('/pathtomyfile/atom')

fullcounts = tree.xpath('//ns:fullcount',
                namespaces={'ns': "http://purl.org/atom/ns#"})

print etree.tostring(fullcounts[0])
```

**Which would give you:**

```
<fullcount xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">1</fullcount>
```